# Error Creating an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment using AWS Toolkit (.Net)

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, awsdeploy

Error from command prompt:

```
4 Aug 2017 10:36:18,864 DEBUG AwsAdminTool.CmdLineRunner ....creating application 'smsweb'
24 Aug 2017 10:36:19,419 DEBUG AwsAdminTool.CmdLineRunner ....creating environment 'smsweb-test-roof' with application version 'v20170824003602'
24 Aug 2017 10:36:19,539 DEBUG AwsAdminTool.CmdLineRunner [Error]: **Publish to AWS Elastic Beanstalk failed with exception: No Solution Stack named '64bit Windows Server 2016 R2 v1.2.0 running IIS 10.0' found.**,
24 Aug 2017 10:36:19,539 DEBUG AwsAdminTool.CmdLineRunner Inner Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
24 Aug 2017 10:36:19,558 DEBUG AwsAdminTool.CmdLineRunner
```

I get the above error when deploying to a new environment that needs to be created.

I have also considered using the latest awsdeploy tool (version 1.12.1.5).

Any ideas as to why I am seeing this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this again by updating the SolutionStack parameter in the deploy file and it worked. I think before I was updating the wrong file...whoops.